# Attribute error:- TensorFlow has no attribute "Session". How should I solve this error? I am using Mac Catalina OS

Tags: tensorflow, session, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

Attribute error:- TensorFlow has no attribute "Session".
How should I solve this error?
 Please look at the image in the link
[Tensorflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORlff.png)

Comment: Rather than posting image of error/code please post the actual error/code so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: You are probably using TensorFlow 2.0 with a tutorial/code made for TensorFlow 1.x, which is not compatible with 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Once I had similar problems after I had installed `tensorflow-estimator`. I reinstalled tensorflow and everything went back to normal again.

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow
```

or

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```